# Google Ads are crashing on Android 9, after recent release of Android chrome 87.0.4280.101

Tags: android, google-chrome, admob, google-ads-api

Suddenly We are experiencing crashes when loading Ads from Google Ads SDK.
The crash is coming on Android 9 running devices and having latest chrome `version.87.0.4280.101`

Ad SDK used:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:19.6.0'
```

The crash is only reported on the Google play console and not on Firebase Crashlytics.

This seems to be an issue of webview which is used internally by Google Ad SDK.

Anybody else is getting the same crashes recently..

Logs attached.

```
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/lavender/lavender:9/PKQ1.180904.001/V10.3.5.0.PFGINXM:user/release-keys'
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: pid: 21385, tid: 21549, name: ThreadPoolForeg  >>> com.indiamart.m <<<
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
    '
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000081  x2  000000007fffffff  x3  0000000000000000
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  7f7f7f7fffff7f7f
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
2020-12-12 10:42:35.792 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x12 00000000ffffff80  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffff000000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
2020-12-12 10:42:35.793 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007737c11218  x17 0000007737b21450  x18 0000000000000010  x19 0000007685e06c98
2020-12-12 10:42:35.793 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000007685e06cb0  x21 0000007685e06ca8  x22 000000000000004f  x23 0000007737c133c0
2020-12-12 10:42:35.793 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x24 00000076a20c8000  x25 0000007685e07588  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000007685e067e8
2020-12-12 10:42:35.793 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007685e06c30
2020-12-12 10:42:35.793 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007685e067d0  lr  000000769f8dd854  pc  000000769f8dda34
2020-12-12 10:42:35.814 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-12-12 10:42:35.815 21819-21819/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000001ab6a34  /data/app/com.android.chrome-SDEgJLhE8mN6xW_77wZdEQ==/base.apk (offset 0xd27000)
```

Comment: You should file a bug report of Ads Sdk Google Group or on Chrome Bug Tracker.

Comment: already done that, checking if someone else is facing it & found cause.